# Dual-Boot issue (and much more...)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I downloaded today and installed the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04 something,and i installed it via Live CD. All went well, I created a partition of 150GB and another one of 508MB (the latter for the swap space) and when i restarted the PC it automatically booted to Ubuntu, it didnt ask for which OS to boot to.

I booted to Ubuntu alright, but noticed that it wasnt working properly - the mouse lags and leaves trails of itself, typing had a delay - and so i figured that i shouldnt have installed the 64-bit version cause i have 4GB of memory. I tried downloading the boot repair tool by typing in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

but i received an error saying something like: cannot locate /cow in grub. I googled it but couldn't find anything. Then i typed:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and it did find my Win7 installation. Next time i rebooted i was prompted which OS to boot from and I chose the win7 loader. All went well and there I was at my windows. I then proceeded in formatting the disk partitions that were used by Ubuntu, but then when i rebooted there was an error on the screen saying that there is no bootable device. I rebooted and pressed F12 to access the boot options and  I found 2 of them, one with the tag P0 and one P1. I tried both of them, the first one redirected me to the previous message, whereas the 2nd one redirected me to a message saying:

```
grub rescue>
```

I had no idea what to do, so I re-installed the Ubuntu OS from the cd and ran the update-grub command again (boot-repair still didn't work). Now i get prompted each time which OS to boot, but my Ubuntu installation does not work. When I choose Ubuntu, I get a black screen with some trails of colour on the top and nothing happens from there on (I left it like that for 15 mins so I guess nothing will happen after that).

What I wish to do is delete Ubuntu and always boot Windows . Feel free to ask any details.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the partitions and link to it? Use http://imgur.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

boot into windows, resize the ubuntu partition to as small as it can be, then download, install, and run easybcd. Recreate the mbr with it and then delete the ubuntu partition and refresh the boot options with easybcd. It will be just like a windows install and nothing else

Comment: I get an error saying: The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The system cannot find the file specified.

Would you like to manually load a BCD registry for EASYBCD to manage?

Comment: I'm trying to remember as the last time I had windows on a machine I actually use is like 2 months ago

Comment: plz do try to remember

Comment: awesome! i wrote the mbr, then loaded the boot settings, no issues now, and then set the win7 booter. thanks :D